# Uploading zip file from Android to dot net server

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload a zip file from files from the android application to the server. I am initiating the HttpEntity object and uploading it in bytes using OutputStream and utf-8 char-set.

```
            HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                .addPart("Solution", fileBody).build();
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/zip");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/zip;");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                try (OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
                    byte[] input = entity.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
                    os.write(input, 0, input.length);
                }
                return connection.getInputStream();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Exception", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
```

On the server, I am receiving empty "Files" object under HttpContext.Current.Request.

```
                [HttpPost]
            [Route("UploadProblemSolution")]
            public HttpResponseMessage UploadProblemSolution()
            {
                try
                {
                    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                    if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //save zip files
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
```

Comment: `and utf-8 char-set` You cannot use a charset as that is for text documents. You should just upload the bytes of the zip file. Nothing else.

Comment: What is fileBody? We cannot see that. I think you have to add the file in another way. With addFile or addFilePart?

Comment: `FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(filePath), "application/zip");`

Comment: here filePath is the absolute path of the zip file.

Comment: You should give mire info.